# django queryset with count filter

Tags: django, filter, count

I've done the entire Django Tutorial, but I couldn't figure out how to make the website display only Polls with Choices count bigger than 0.
I know that Poll.objects.get(pk=1).choice_set.count() would return the number of choices I have.
So I tried the filter Poll.objects.filter(choice_set.count()>0) and it didn't work.
Can someone help me please? Thanks

This is my actual queryset.

```
queryset=Poll.objects.filter(pub_date__lte=timezone.now).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```

Comment: can you post your models? choice and poll?

Answer (score 4):

```
queryset=Poll.objects.annotate(count=Count('choice')).filter(
    pub_date__lte=timezone.now, count__gt=0).order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
```